# #define value in stringFormat?

Tags: ios, iphone, macros, nsstring

I have a define:

```
hashdefine kPingServerToSeeIfInternetIsOn  "http://10.0.0.8"
```

then in code I with to use it:

```
NSString *theURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", kPingServerToSeeIfInternetIsOn];
```

I get an exception.

What's the best way to define the const for the application and use it in a `NSString` init?

Comment: By the way, you could simplify this particular code with something like "NSString *theURL = kPingServerToSeeIfInternetIsOn;" or even more simply, but replacing any reference to theURL with kPingServerToSeeIfInternetIsOn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a header file, e.g. `MyAppConstants.h`. Add the following:

```
extern NSString * const kPingServerToSeeIfInternetIsOn;
```

In the definition, e.g. `MyAppConstants.m`, add:

```
NSString * const kPingServerToSeeIfInternetIsOn = @"http://10.0.0.8";
```

In your class implementation, add:

```
#import "MyAppConstants.h"
```

You can use the constant as you have done already.

Comment: While I strongly agree with using consts rather than defines, I strongly disagree with creating a file like "MyAppConstants.h". This makes code-reuse very hard. Put constants in the files that logically provide them, or at least in the file that uses them. But don't create a central dumping ground for all system constants.

Comment: There is a place for having constants in the same file as the class. But I do find having my constants hinted in only a few header files (organized by larger code function) makes my troubleshooting *much* easier. It's no fun hunting them down or having to refactor a bunch of them from different places. At the very least, develop a consistent and informative naming scheme for your constants and stick to it like glue.

Answer (score 9):

You've #defined it as a C string.

If you want it as an Objective-C String, you need

```
#define kPingServerToSeeIfInternetIsOn @"http://10.0.0.8"
```